# mysql function to compare similars strings

Tags: mysql, function, comparison, similarity

i need to search on my database for registers using "almost" the same email...

my email is abc@gmail.com i need to see if we have register with small variations of this emails, like... abc1@gmail.com or abc@gmail1.com or abc@ggmail.com

I tried already fulltext index like:

```
select codcliente,
    email,
    MATCH(email) AGAINST('"abc@gmail.com"' in BOOLEAN MODE)
from cliente
where MATCH(email) AGAINST('"abc@gmail.com"' in BOOLEAN MODE);
```

but no success...

Any help?

Answer (score 1):

```
       SELECT count(email) FROM cliente
       WHERE email SOUNDS LIKE 'abc@gmail.com';
```

Try this

If you want to compare then the logic should be implemented in some language which goes like this

```
if count > 0 then exist.
```

Comment: yes it works, but i would want to be able to specify the percentage of similarity...something like: show me only the strings that are 97% similar to this one.....

Comment: Not sure about that.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT codcliente, email,
FROM cliente
WHERE email LIKE '%abc@gmail.com%';
```